# SELECT query to get child elements from xml datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, t-sql

I have the following SQL script (and the XML structure at the bottom):

```
DECLARE @questions XML

SELECT 
    t.Col.value('QuestionId[1]', 'int') AS  QuestionId,
    t.Col.value('Options[1]/string[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') Options 
FROM 
    @questions.nodes ('//Question') t(Col) 
WHERE 
    t.Col.value('QuestionId[1]', 'int') = 5
```

The `SELECT` query is returning only first row for `Options` child string (*Blue*). How can I get all the values as 4 rows (*Blue, Red, White, Black*) by changing `t.Col.value('Options[1]/string[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')` ?

```
SET @questions = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Questions>
       <Question>
          <RowType>Question</RowType>
          <Required>False</Required>
          <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
          <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
          <QuestionId>5</QuestionId>
          <Options>
             <string>Blue</string>
             <string>Red</string>
             <string>White</string>
             <string>Black</string>
          </Options>
       </Question>
       <Question>
          <RowType>Question</RowType>
          <Required>False</Required>
          <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
          <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
          <QuestionId>6</QuestionId>
          <Options />
       </Question>
    </Questions>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `apply` :

```
SELECT t.col.value('(./QuestionId)[1]','int') AS QuestionId,
       t1.Col.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Options
FROM @questions.nodes ('/Questions/Question') t(Col) OUTER APPLY 
     t.Col.nodes('Options/*') t1(Col);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go down to reach `<string>` tag level with `Questions/Question/Options/string` and then go back one level to get `QuestionId`:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.col.value('(//QuestionId)[1]','int') AS QuestionId,
    t.Col.value('(.)[1]' ,'varchar(50)')   AS Options 
FROM @questions.nodes ('Questions/Question/Options/string') t(Col) 
WHERE t.Col.value('(//QuestionId)[1]', 'int') = 5
```

Results:

[image]

As pointed out in comments the above solution will not work when another `<question>` tag appears before the one that must be selected.

This is the new input scenario with 4 `<question>` tags:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Questions>
    <Question>
        <RowType>Question</RowType>
        <Required>False</Required>
        <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
        <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
        <QuestionId>6</QuestionId>
        <Options />
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <RowType>Question</RowType>
        <Required>False</Required>
        <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
        <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
        <QuestionId>5</QuestionId>
        <Options>
            <string>Blue</string>
            <string>Red</string>
            <string>White</string>
            <string>Black</string>
        </Options>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <RowType>Question</RowType>
        <Required>False</Required>
        <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
        <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
        <QuestionId>7</QuestionId>
        <Options />
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <RowType>Question</RowType>
        <Required>False</Required>
        <QuestionText>select color</QuestionText>
        <QuestionType>Radio Buttons</QuestionType>
        <QuestionId>8</QuestionId>
        <Options>
            <string>Blue</string>
            <string>Red</string>
            <string>White</string>
            <string>Black</string>
        </Options>
    </Question>
</Questions>
```

Using the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.col.value('((.)/QuestionId)[1]','int') AS QuestionId,
    u.Col.value('(.)[1]' ,'varchar(50)')     AS Options 
FROM @questions.nodes ('Questions/*')    t(Col) 
    OUTER APPLY t.Col.nodes('Options/*') u(Col)
```

these are the results:

[image]

applying the where clause leads to the desired results:

[image]

Comment: Works great. Ty

Comment: This is not working as expected. You were right about the answer with the given xml. I ran into an issue when I the data has many more Question elements. If I have Question element above the first element with QuestionId 5 it will not work. I am getting no rows. 
What I would like is for a set of questions , get the Options/string value of the given QuestionId.

Comment: This works too (very similar to Yogesh answer. Marking his answer as a accepted answer as he responded first). Thanks